# How to perform 2 operation in 'THEN' section of case when in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have build a query like this

```
 select IP,
(case when MINUTE_NUM+(SEGMENT_DURATION_TIME_SEC_QTY/60)>60 then 
 hour_24_hour_format_num+1
end) as end_hr,
(case when MINUTE_NUM+(SEGMENT_DURATION_TIME_SEC_QTY/60)<60 then MINUTE_NUM+
(SEGMENT_DURATION_TIME_SEC_QTY/60) 
end)as end_min 
from a608232_new_calls_with_tmst;
```

I want to know can I perform 2 operations in `then` section of the query. 
Something like this

```
 select IP,
(case when MINUTE_NUM+(SEGMENT_DURATION_TIME_SEC_QTY/60)>60 then 
 hour_24_hour_format_num+1 and minute_num=0
end) as end_hr,
```

When I try to do this it throws syntax error near `and`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Update:

```
  This one worked for me.   

 select 
 IP,hour_24_hour_format_num,MINUTE_NUM,SEGMENT_DURATION_TIME_SEC_QTY/60 
 min_duration,
(case when MINUTE_NUM+(SEGMENT_DURATION_TIME_SEC_QTY/60)>60 then 
hour_24_hour_format_num+1
      when MINUTE_NUM+(SEGMENT_DURATION_TIME_SEC_QTY/60)<60 then 
hour_24_hour_format_num
end) as end_hr,
(case when MINUTE_NUM+(SEGMENT_DURATION_TIME_SEC_QTY/60)>60 then 0
  when MINUTE_NUM+(SEGMENT_DURATION_TIME_SEC_QTY/60)<60 then MINUTE_NUM+
 (SEGMENT_DURATION_TIME_SEC_QTY/60) 
 end)as end_min
 from a608232_new_calls_with_tmst;
```

Comment: Nope, you need to repeat the `case`.  Are you using SQL Server or Oracle?

Comment: i am using oracle

Comment: So, what do you think that will do? Assign the value 0 to MINUTE_NUM? A SELECT statement does not ASSIGN values to anything.

Comment: fyi: The `tsql` tag is explicitly _not_ to be used for Oracle related queries.

Comment: Why is there a tsql tag if you are using Oracle?

Comment: Well, you could have the `case` expression return an [object](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADOBJ/adobjint.htm) containing `hour_24_hour_format_num` and `minute_num` attributes and then extract them in an enclosing query... but depending on what you need this for it might be overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CASE` expression evaluates a list of conditions and returns one of multiple possible result expressions. **As it returns a single value, it cannot be used to update multiple columns or operations.**

Comment: The `CASE` as used in a `SELECT` is an *expression* not a *statement*.  Some database scripting language do support a `CASE` statement -- and it is quite different.